# Comparing three arrays

Tags: python, arrays, if-statement, boolean, conditional-statements

I would like to ask, why this is returning 'True' (or what is the code doing when it is written like this):

```
def isItATriple(first,second,third):
if first[0] == second[0] == third[0] or first[0] != second[0] != third[0]:
    if first[1] == second[1] == third[1] or first[1] !=second[1] != third[1]:
        if first[2] == second[2] == third[2] or first[2] != second[2] != third[2]:
            if (first[3] == second[3] == third[3]) or (first[3] != second[3] != third[3]):
                return True
            else:
                return False
        else:
            return False
    else:
        return False
else:
    return False

print(isItATriple([0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,1],[0,0,0,0]))
```

Comment: Because `(first[3] != second[3] != third[3])` ==> `(first[3] != second[3]...)` && (...second[3] != third[3]).

Answer (score 1):

Let analyze:

first if:

```
if first[0] == second[0] == third[0] or \
        first[0] != second[0] != third[0]:
```

The first (before or) is True - because at 0 index all lists have 0;
If so - the condition after or is not checked (because python is lazy) `True or Anything` gives True.

The second if:

```
if first[1] == second[1] == third[1] or \
            first[1] !=second[1] != third[1]:
```

Exactly same as above - 1 element of each list is equal - so it's True here.

The third if:

```
if first[2] == second[2] == third[2] \
                or first[2] != second[2] != third[2]:
```

The same. Generally: True.

The fourth if:

```
if first[3] == second[3] == third[3] or \
                    first[3] != second[3] != third[3]:
```

And here - the first condition (before or) is False and the second is True. So this is why your method returns True.

The second condition is evaluated to:

```
0 != 1 != 0
```

In other words this mean:

```
0 != 1 and 1 != 0
```

And finally:

```
True  # because 0 is different than 1;
```

It is a common case when you use operators like this:

```
1 < x < 10
```

This mean:

```
1 < x and x < 10
```

But to be honest - this code is pretty ugly :)

Let me show you how can you do this more `nicely`.

```
def myIsATriple(first, second, third):
    return first == second == third
```

List comparison works pretty well in python :) so you do not need to do it manually, examples:

```
myIsATriple([0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 0, 0])  # False
myIsATriple([0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0])  # True
myIsATriple([0, 'a', 0, 0], [0, 'a', 0, 0], [0, 'b', 0, 0])  # False
myIsATriple([0, 'a', 1, 0], [0, 'a', 1, 0], [0, 'a', 1, 0])  # True
myIsATriple([0, {'a': 2}, 1, 0], [0, {'a': 2}, 1, 0], [0, {'a': 3}, 1, 0])  # False
myIsATriple([0, {'a': 2}, 1, 0], [0, {'a': 2}, 1, 0], [0, {'a': 2}, 1, 0])  # True
```

Happy coding!